# Wildly different answers replicating a GEE model from SPSS

Tags: spss, statsmodels, generalized-estimating-equations

##### Describe the bug

I'm attempting to replicate a GEE model in statsmodels from a published paper that used SPSS (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33279717/). I am getting very different answers for what seems like the same input structure. I even signed up for a free trial of SPSS and can confirm SPSS gives the answers reported in the paper.

The input matrices are being loaded from the same .csv (and I filter using pandas to achieve the same dataframe as in SPSS).

##### Code Sample, a copy-pastable example if possible

```
USE ALL. 
COMPUTE filter_$=(BehTaskNum = 1 or BehTaskNum = 2 or (BehTaskNum = 3 and  BlockNumber = 6)).  
FILTER BY filter_$. 
EXECUTE.
GENLIN DifferenceScore BY White Right (ORDER=ASCENDING) 
  /MODEL White Right White*Right INTERCEPT=YES 
 DISTRIBUTION=NORMAL LINK=IDENTITY 
  /CRITERIA SCALE=MLE PCONVERGE=1E-006(ABSOLUTE) SINGULAR=1E-012 ANALYSISTYPE=3(WALD) CILEVEL=95 
    LIKELIHOOD=FULL 
  /REPEATED SUBJECT=participantID SORT=YES
    CORRTYPE=EXCHANGEABLE ADJUSTCORR=YES COVB=ROBUST MAXITERATIONS=1000 PCONVERGE=1e-006(ABSOLUTE) 
    UPDATECORR=1 
  /PRINT CPS DESCRIPTIVES MODELINFO FIT SUMMARY SOLUTION.
```

```py
fam = sm.families.Gaussian(link=sm.families.links.identity)
ind = sm.cov_struct.Exchangeable()
GEE_model = smf.gee("DifferenceScore ~ White * Right", groups="ParticipantID",
                data=stim_df_with_facename,cov_struct=ind, family=fam)
stim_model_out = GEE_model.fit(maxiter=1000)
stim_model_out.summary()
```

SPSS results:

[image]

statsmodel results:

[image]

The results aren't even close (seems statsmodels isn't converging--and I've tried up to 10000 iterations but get the same result). I should point out if I run a model with an additional predictor (White*Right+Macro) the results are closer...but still quite a bit different:

SPSS results:

[image]

statsmodel results:

[image: ![]

I'm much more familiar with Mixed Effect models...but trying those in statsmodels were not replicating the GEE results either (even though in principle they should be similar).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're less *wildly* different once you correct for the different contrasts the two programs use.  SPSS has 1 as the reference level of the two variables and `statsmodels` has 0.

Here are the fitted values for the four combinations of the two binary variables

```
        statsmodels   SPSS
neither     -0.0284 -0.024
white       -0.0134 -0.021
right       -0.0156 -0.015
both         0.1117  0.115
```

That's still more different than I'd expect, and it's a bad sign that the `statsmodels` estimate hasn't converged. So I ran the model with two different R implementations (`gee` and `geeM`). They also give different answers, but more importantly they agree there's an estimation problem. The working correlation parameter is trying to be more negative than is possible given the cluster size, giving a non-positive-definite working correlation matrix. (I note that neither your SPSS nor `statsmodels` output shows the estimated working correlation)

So, I think neither result is really reliable for this dataset, and the exchangeable working correlation model isn't stable. If the estimates haven't converged in 1000 iterations, they aren't going to (and looking at the R version, they aren't showing any signs of converging).

I would suggest falling back to working independence. For working independence, SPSS and R give the same answers (I didn't check `statsmodels`). There's some potential efficiency gain from the exchangeable working correlation, but not if the correlation parameter can't be estimated reliably.

Comment: Yup you nailed it: inconsistencies arise from the exchangeable working correlation. SPSS and statsmodels give nearly identical answers once you set SPSS to DESCENDING to account for the reversed coding and setting the working correlation to INDEPENDENT. Also a great sign: the GEE coefficients now match those from the statsmodels Mixed Effects model, as expected for linear models. Thanks for the help!!